# MassTransit SagaStateMachine testing shouldn't be this hard, should it?

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to write unit tests for MassTransit SagaStateMachine.

The SagaStateMachine has some activities associated to it, so I'm having to write a service provider and add it when configuring the receive endpoint.

My issue is when I try to resolve ISagaRepository as InMemorySagaRepository it returns null and hence forth I can't confirm anything actually worked in my mocks.

Is there an easier way to do this? I'm at my wits end.

The activities include a discord socket client which I've mocked and injected in the service provider and you can see my source here:
https://github.com/robertkirkham88/NightFuryBot/blob/master/tests/NFB.UI.DiscordBot.Tests/StateMachines/FlightStateMachineTests.cs

Line 146 is where the issue lies but I might be doing something wrong with my setting up the bus. The unit tests on MassTransit and Automatonymous are not helpful and I can't find any other solution on git/stackoverflow.

```
var repo = this.provider.GetService<ISagaRepository<FlightState>>() as InMemorySagaRepository<FlightState>;
Assert.NotNull(repo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 7.0.4 of MassTransit included container-based configuration for the `InMemoryTestHarness`, making it easier to configure tests when using a container.

The [Release Notes](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.0.4.html#in-memory-test-harness) cover usage, which is also shown below.

Based on the code you linked, you would need:

```
services.AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<FlightStateMachine, FlightState>()
        .InMemoryRepository();

    cfg.AddSagaTestHarness<FlightState>();
});
```

And then, once the container is built, you can resolve the test harness and start it.

```
var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();

await harness.Start();
```

The state machine should already be configured on an endpoint, so your `Publish` calls should deliver events to the state machine.

> Also, you should only need `ISagaRepository<T>` to check if sagas are present.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. I want to test state machine sage with activities resolved via DI. I've tried solution provided by [@Chris Patterson] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63999346/14864310) with `AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness` method but it looks like the `harness` does not consume my messages to the saga. It started to work just after adding the following code before harness start:

```
harness.OnConfigureInMemoryReceiveEndpoint += cfg =>
{
    cfg.ConfigureSagas(provider.GetRequiredService<IBusRegistrationContext>());
}

await harness.Start();
```

I'm not sure that it's intended or I've missed something.